# 403 Error - Method doesn't allow unregistered callers: Unable to write data into Google Sheet using Python script run through Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to write data into Google Sheet using Python script. Most importantly, I want to auotemate it by using Google Cloud Function. However, even I could run the code successfully using my local computer environment by pointing to the path of the credentials, I receive error when running it in Google Cloud Function.Even I go to the link the error code points me to, I still have no ideas how to solve the issues. You could review the below script and error code I use and receive. Note that I am using a service account to get access to Google Sheet, not OAuth Client ID. Any thoughts?

This is the python script I use in Google Cloud Function. I do some research and find that since I am running in Google Cloud, I should use googleapiclient.discovery to get the credentials. What is wrong in my code?

```
import pygsheets
import pandas as pd
import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


def gen_google_sheet():
    """
    Get the service credentials to be used to query a google sheet
    """
    #scope for read and write
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
    creds, project = google.auth.default(scopes=scopes)
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
    #authorization
    gc = pygsheets.authorize(credentials=creds)
    """
    gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='compute_engine_service_acc_api_key.json')
    """

    # Create empty dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    # Create a column
    df['name'] = ['John', 'Steve', 'Sarah']

    #open the google spreadsheet (where 'PY to Gsheet Test' is the name of my sheet)
    sh = gc.open('Python Write Test')

    #select the first sheet 
    wks = sh[0]

    #update the first sheet with df, starting at cell B2. 
    return wks.set_dataframe(df,(1,1))
```

Below is the error I receive when running in Google Cloud

> {
> "error": {
> "code": 403,
> "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
> "domain": "global",
> "reason": "forbidden"
> }
> ],
> "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
> }
> }>

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the quota project. 2 Solutions for that

1. Use the client_option parameter

```
 service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds,client_options={"quota_project_id": "<your project ID>"})
```

2. Use env var `GOOGLE_CLOUD_QUOTA_PROJECT`=`<your project ID>`

Comment: for your information, the below is the error I received. {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Method doesn't allow unregistered callers (callers without established identity). Please use API Key or other form of API consumer identity to call this API.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

Comment: Do you use a project where you have permission and the API activated?

Comment: I could run the script in local environment (personal laptop). I downloaded the JSON key from the service account and can use it to write data into Google Sheet. But when I switch to Google Cloud function, I come across the error. Do you think it is my script issues or permissions and API activation issues? If latter, any ways I could check what I have missed? Since the script can be run in local environment, I just don’t know what I miss

Comment: There is something strange. This error is normal with a user credential (and my code fix this issue in that case), but not with a service account credential, on your computer or on Google Cloud. Do you have extra code or extra configuration that can alter the expected behavior?

Comment: It seems to me the issues comes from how to get the Google Sheet API in the cloud environment. Do you think there is another way to do it? Say instead of using google.auth.default and googleapiclient, one could upload the JSON file to Cloud Storage and then in pygsheets.authorize, write as pygsheets.authorize(service_file='gs://bucket_name/file_name.json'). Do you think it works? I tried but a error is saying that it cannot find the path.

Comment: I totally not advice to use a service account key file. It's generally a bad practice to use it. Your use case is strange, I never had it with Cloud Run (never tried with Cloud Functions). Can you get inspiration from one of my article? It's between Cloud Build and GSheet. I used impersonation to scope correctly my credential and be able to reach GSheet (it was a scope issue, not a quota project issue...) https://medium.com/google-cloud/access-to-google-workspace-documents-from-cloud-build-3001c2883b66

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will further investigate